# how to prevent a path to be scanned with media store external uri

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediastore, android-cursor

I have used this for scan all video file on android

```java
public class FileBrowser extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.file_browser);

        
        TextView lists = findViewById(R.id.file_managerTextView);
        
        List<File> files = getAllMediaFilesOnDevice(FileBrowser.this);
        
        for(int i=0;i<files.size();i++){
            lists.append(files.get(i).getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
        }
        
    }
    public static List<File> getAllMediaFilesOnDevice(Context context) {
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null);
                
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            files.clear();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                int lastPoint = path.lastIndexOf(".");
                path = path.substring(0, lastPoint) + path.substring(lastPoint).toLowerCase();
                files.add(new File(path));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return files;
    }
}
```

it's work but problem is given output is from path `/storage/emulated/0/` and `/sdcard` so this function return duplicate files because files in `/storage/emulated/0/` and `/sdcard` are same
So, my question is how to prevent any of these two path to be scanned by mediastore

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to insert an if condition:

```
String filepath = files.get(i).getAbsolutePath();
if(!filepath.startsWith("/sdcard"))
{
    lists.append(filepath + "\n");
}
```

You can replace `/sdcard` with `/storage/emulated/0` depending on which path you would like to use. A word of warning - some phones have different internal storage paths, and using 1 of these 2 might not work properly. For that, you would need to check first, whether the `File` object exists & then proceed.